# OpenContainer is showing a background?

Tags: flutter

I'm using openContainer to animate the transition of the FAB to a view/screen - however, there seems to be a box around the fab. How do I remove this ?

```
OpenContainer(

          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          closedBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) =>
              FloatingActionButton(
            elevation: 10,
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,

            onPressed: () {

              action();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          openBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) {
            return MyScreen();
          },
          tappable: false,
        ));
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem and found the solution. This is an alternative to removing the box - following the [example](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/master/packages/animations/example/lib/container_transition.dart) from the animation github repo:

1. Replace FloatingActionButton with SizedBox containing a height and width
2. Include closedElevation property in OpenContainer to maintain the elevation effect
3. Include closedShape property in OpenContainer to make SizedBox round

```
OpenContainer(
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
  closedColor: Colors.pink,
  closedBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action){
    return SizedBox(
      height: 56,
      width: 56,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  openBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) {
    return MyScreen();
  },
  tappable: false,
  closedElevation: 6.0,
  closedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(56 / 2),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Ahh perfect, i thought it was a Fab when I saw an example gif. Thank you, and thanks for linking the example.

Answer (score 1):

try this and it's done

```
floatingActionButton: OpenContainer(
        closedColor: Colors.blue,
        closedShape: const CircleBorder(),
        closedElevation: 6,
        transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        closedBuilder: (BuildContext c, openWidget) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            elevation: 0,
            onPressed: openWidget,
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          );
        },
        openBuilder: (BuildContext c, VoidCallback action) => SomeNewPage(),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

solved liked that

```
 closedColor: Colors.transparent,
 closedElevation: 12,
 closedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),),
 openColor: Colors.transparent,
 openElevation: 0,
```